# How do I create a new syntax hilighting set for Ti-Npsire/ Ti-BASIC in Sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, ti-basic

I'm using the awesome Sublime Text 2 to write in TI-NSPIRE/ Ti-BASIC programs for Nspire Calculator, but it has no syntax highlighting for TI-NSPIRE/ Ti-BASIC. It would be handy to add TI-NSPIRE/ Ti-BASIC's commands. Does anybody know how I would create a syntax highlighting set for Sublime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a new [syntax definition](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) for your language. It's basically a set of regular expressions that define [scopes](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes), which can then be highlighted using an appropriately-customized theme. If you'd like to look before you leap, browse the `Packages` directory (reachable through `Preferences -> Browse Packages`) and look for `LanguageName.tmLanguage` files in any `LanguageName` directory (they may be in a `Syntaxes` subdirectory). These are text files are in PLIST or XML format and are viewable within ST2 itself. Good luck!

Comment: This is a good answer, and I'd rather not make another competing response just to add this suggestion: there's a plugin called  [AAAPackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/AAAPackageDev) which is *invaluable* in the creation of syntax definitions.

Comment: @ProtractorNinja - AAAPackageDev is mentioned right at the top of my first link, which is to the official docs. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: So it is! I should've checked. At the very least, I've brought more attention to it with redundancy—you know, just in case someone misses how the *entire tutorial* is based on AAAPackageDev.

Comment: Thanks. Now Im trying

I'm doing as suggested! BUT ...
I'm stuck at this point: what does "foldingStartMarker" mean?
documentation

https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=foldingStartMarker

I found this:

foldingStartMarker
     Currently ignored. Used for code folding.

Some help!?

Comment: @TRMPereira - you can ignore this if you don't want to do code folding. It basically matches any line, like the beginning of a class or function, where you would want to fold up the code to make it smaller. Also, if you like my answer, please click the check mark to select it as the best answer - both of us will earn reputation points for it :)

Comment: @MattDMo Ty for your kind answer... if I have some trouble in the process can u help, more!?! Again: ty for your time!

OFF: what we do with reputations points? ;-)

Comment: @TRMPereira - If you have further questions, just post and tag them appropriately, and all of us can help you. As for reputation, just read through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to find out how StackOverflow and the rest of the StackExchange network works.

Comment: @MattDMo nothing better than a FAQ, ty again!